# Is it possible to embed canvas apps on Dynamics 365 Portal?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

Is it possible to embed canvas apps on Dynamics 365 Portal? Canvas app should be visible to both logged in user and anonymous user on Portal.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to embed Canvas Apps inside a Power Apps Portals.

It's in public preview the possibility to add PCF Components but nothing more.

Comment: Hi Guido, I was referring to Dynamics 365 portal not power apps portal.

Comment: so you are referring to a standard Dynamics 365 instance or to a Portals (that now are called Power Apps Portals)?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'Dynamics 365 Portal' you mean one of the Dynamics apps running on power platform (i.e a model driven app), then yes it is possible to embed canvas apps into the model driven forms.

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/embed-canvas-app-in-form) as a starting point.

The only portal is the power apps portal which as Guido already mentioned, it is not supported for currently.